# Remove the Media Library button if current user is not an administrator - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When I add a gallery to the post, I want the **Media library** button to appear only for the administrator. nobody else will see. how can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what you need to give us so we can help and so you're more like yo get a good answer, and update your question with details of what you have tried and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you first need to add a function in the "functions.php" file that adds a class to the body depending on the current user role :

```
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Add class to body depending on the current user role, i.e. role-*role
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

function role_body_class($classes) 
{
    global $current_user;
    foreach ($current_user->roles as $role)
        $classes .= ' role-' . $role;
    return trim($classes);
}

add_filter('admin_body_class', 'role_body_class');
```

Then we want to hide the button "Media library" only if body doesn't have the class "role-adminitrator". We can't do that in our `style.css` file because this file is not loaded in the admin page. To do that we can create a new CSS file called "admin.css" and enqueue it for the admin page.

```
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Enqueue admin styles
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

function my_admin_theme_style()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('my-admin-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . './admin.css');
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_theme_style');
```

Now the last step is to write the css needed to hide the "Media Library" button if current user is not an administrator. Open the "admin.css" file and add this code :

```
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Hide the Media Library button if the current user is not an administrator
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

body:not(.role-administrator).post-type-post class-or-id-of-the-media-library-button 
{
    display: none;
}
```

You just need to replace `class-or-id-of-the-media-library-button` by something that can select the button (class or id).

Hope this helps!

Comment: While this answer is perfectly fine (and deserved a +1), please be aware that advanced users might be able to override the CSS and display the button again. "Disabling functionality" through CSS should therefore only be used with non-critical elements.